# Update Typescript in Angular2 project

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have an Angular2 project using Typescript, in Visual Studio. I want to update Typescript from 1.8 to 2.0.x. In my system I have updated typescript and `tsc -v` logs `Version 2.0.10`
The package.json, among others, contains

```
"devDependencies": {
    ....
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.3.1",
    ...
}
```

In order to update typescript, is it enough to change the version to  `"typescript": "^2.0.10"` in the package.json? Also, what is the relation of typescript and typings version, when it comes to update?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Updating the typescript version in your package.json and running `npm install` will be enough to upgrade the version you are using for your project.

Typescript 2.x has introduced a new way to manage types, using the @types/... qualifier npm packages - you can still use the typings you have been using before however - but you might wish to update that to the latest version which from npm at the time of writing this answer is 2.0.0

If you are interested, theres more info and a discussion about the new @types here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/

Comment: Let's say that I have 10 libraries that i am using in my project, and I install typings for each of them using "npm install --save @types/eachLibrary" and one day a new Typescript version pops up, then do I need to run again the install command for each of my libraries to update their typings?

Comment: nope the @types packages are managed independently of typescript. So you can just install the new version of typescript without worrying about the @types. A handy npm package you might be interested in if you don't know about it already is npm-check-updates: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates - you can run `ncu` in the terminal from your project location and it will tell you if any of your dependencies have an update available

Comment: Great, thanks! One more question, do I need to reinstall libraries that are already installed using the "old way", but using @types this time?

Comment: nope you should be good to go with the versions you have - not all libraries will have an @types/.. package and the two are separate in terms of installation

Answer (score 35):

## For Exact version

- npm install typescript@2.0.10 --save-dev

## For latest release

- npm install typescript@latest --save-dev

Comment: I used the first command and I got this error. 

ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=2.7.2 and <2.8.0 but 3.7.2 was found instead.

Comment: Try using the specific version required.

Comment: I just need typescript 3 version only in one module. And as you can see in error I'm not able to run ng-serve command also.

Comment: you can't use different versions in a single project (say different for different modules)

Comment: Yeah I know that, So do you have any way to fix this issue?

Comment: I can't create a new project and setup again with versions because I have to deliver the app in this week. I hope you can understand my situation.

Comment: I understand that, but there is no use case like this, I don't event think that this is possible, may I know your applications Angular version?

Comment: My project Angular is : 6.0.2